# C# Combobox not displaying items

Tags: c#, combobox, setter

I am trying to populate a combobox in C#, but for some reason, the items do not appear.

```
public List<string> items
{
    set
    {
        combobox.Items.Clear();
        foreach(string s in value)
        {
            combobox.Items.Add(s);
        }
        combobox.Update();
    }
}
```

This seems like incredibly straightforward code.  I simply cannot see what is wrong.
It is being called like this:

```
private void StoreNames(List<string> names)
{
    if (selectionForm.InvokeRequired)
        selectionForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { selectionForm.items = names; });
    else
        selectionForm.items = names;
}
```

Interestingly, it seems to work when `InvokeRequired` returns true, but does not work when it returns false.

EDIT:
I discovered that `selectionForm.IsHandleCreated` is currently `false`.  This is causing `InvokeRequired` to return false, but is also why calling the setter regularly isn't working.  I don't have any idea why `IsHandleCreated` is set to false.  The Form has been Show()n.

Comment: What thread is setting the property?  Is it a timer thread or the main "windows message loop"?

Comment: I think you are going to need to put more info to get a good answer.

Comment: how do you call it?And why are you filling the combobox with a setter?

Comment: Just a note, you probably shouldn't be messing around with Invalidate/Update/Refresh in this context. Just let Items.Add handle that for you.

Comment: Ok, I will add the context right now.

Comment: Also, it didn't work when I didn't have Update, so I added it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Where do you call `StoreNames` and how? Please use `@` when replying so we get notified e.g. @Shadow will notify me that you replied so I can see it and help further.

Comment: @shadow `StoreNames` is called asynchronously. The call comes after I have called `selectionForm.Show()`, however.

Comment: @Daniel sounds like a race condition to me. (resisting the urge to make a bad joke about asynchronous processes)

Comment: @Shadow I tried putting in `while(!selectionForm.IsHandleCreated) Thread.Sleep(100);` at the beginning of StoreNames. Just got stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Daniel you need to show us the code where you are setting that list. doing things like that loop to try and solve this is a bad idea. Focus on finding the correct place to set the combobox data instead.

Comment: @David I do not have access to the code that sets that list; however, it definitely contains the strings that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why your code isn't working - I tried it and it works just fine.

However, below is some more straightforward code which also works - you may find that doing it this way instead makes your problem go away. This does presume that there is not other reason why you need to go through that property - that is quite an unusual way of doing things.

```
public void StoreNames(List<string> input)
{
    if (comboBox1.InvokeRequired)
        comboBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
            StoreNames(input);
        });
    else
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(input.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Here we just pass the list straight to the items.AddRange() method on the comboBox.

I suspect this won't work for you - something else is going on, but I have tried it both from a backgroundworker (where InvokeRequired is true) and from the main UI thread.

Comment: I agree, I don't think that the Add is the issue.  I have provided some additional information in the question that hopefully might help indicate what the problem is.

Comment: @Daniel - where are you calling the code to set your list? It sounds like you are doing it before the form window (hence the handle) has actually been set. Perhaps try putting the code within the form load event or if your are trying some sort of ModelViewPresenter pattern where the presenter is setting that data, be very careful that the form is initialised - perhaps by passing a callback from the presenter to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo that you refer to both combobox and combobox1? Perhaps that is your error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "not appear" as in you can see them when the list displays, or as in you can't even scroll to them?

Combobox has a lot of properties that can affect what you see. Try a bigger value for combobox.MaxDropDownItems.

Comment: I cannot see them, scroll to them, anything. MaxDropDownItems couldn't be the problem because I cannot see even 1 item.

Comment: `Combobox.Items.Count` is equal to 1 and `MaxDropDownItems` is equal to 8.  The drop down menu is empty.

Answer (score 0):

My other answer in this thread is really just showing the way to doing this if you can get at the code providing you with the list. Since it sounds like you cannot, I'm providing this answer.

It sounds like the key problem is that when the property is called the combobox has not yet been initialized. The best answer for that is that make sure that this does not happen within the calling code.

If you can't do that then you should wait for the property to be set before you use it to populate the combobox.

I would do this be having a private list which gets set in the property setter. Within the form load event i would then put some code (possibly within a background worker) that will wait until the private list is not null and then assign it to the combobox.

Have a look at this post by [Jon Skeet here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/447370-how-do-i-wait-until-myvar-true) where he discusses how to correctly wait for a variable to be set by another thread. You will want to be careful when doing this - threading issues can be nasty.

Comment: I'm a bit short on time right now else I'd provide some code too - leave a comment if you want some examples of anything and i'll see about getting back to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I actually figured out what the problem was. My project involves communication with an external device, and I have a singleton class that handles communication. One of its methods had been `delegate`d to a method in my form, and when I destroyed the form, I forgot to -= the delegate.  I was so baffled about why it always worked the first time, but not the second time!